# How to check if an element exist into another element?

Tags: jquery

I'd like, to jQuery, understand if an element exist into another element.

Somethings like :

```
if($('#container').find('.search_element'))
```

must return YES if `.search_element` is into `#container`, NO otherwise.

How can I do it? Tried with $.contains('#container', '.search_element') but seems that this function doesnt works...

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

---

### ¡¡¡UPDATE!!!

See my answer **[** [***HERE***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery#answer-13313296) **]** for a *MUCH* more robust plugin!

---

You could easily shorten @Chris answer with:

```
if($("#container .search_element").length) { ...
```

You could also do the same with a useful plugin i made for this:

## jsFiddle

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.exist) {
        $.extend({
            exist: function(elm) {
                if (typeof elm == null) return false;
                if (typeof elm != "object") elm = $(elm);
                return elm.length ? true : false;
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            exist: function() {
                return $.exist($(this));
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

> **USE**

```
//  With your if statement
if($("#container .search_element").exist()) { ...

//  With ID 
$.exist("#eleID");
//  OR
$("#eleID").exist();

//  With class name
$.exist(".class-name");
//  OR
$(".class-name").exist();

//  With just tag // prolly not best idea aS there will be other tags on site
$.exist("div");
//  OR
$("div").exist();
```

Of course this plugin could be further extended to be much more fancy (handling multiple calls at once, creating non-existing elements based on a pram), but as it stand now, it does a very simple, very needed function ... Does this element exist? return `True` or `False`

## jsFiddle

Comment: Tip (i'm thinking of doing this anyway, but not sure its how people will want to use it) you could edit the plugin to have a callback function. Then you wouldn't need the "if" statement at all.

Answer (score 20):

A simple length check:

```
if($("#container").find(".search_element").length) {
    // If the length is greater than 0, it exists
} else {
    // else, false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.is` and `:has`, just to be complete. I would prefer a solution which tests `.length` though.

```
if($('#container').is(':has(.search_element)')) {
   // I haz that
}
```

- http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 2):

check the length of the array

```
if($('#container').find('.search_element').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a default method for this:

```
$("#container").has(".selector");
```

http://api.jquery.com/has/