# If Div with certain class exists, do something with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class and if it exists, I want to use the variable as a true/false if statement.

HTML

```
<div id="snake" class="snake--mobile">
```

JS

```
var isMobileVersion = document.getElementsByClassName('snake--mobile');
if (isMobileVersion !== null)
  alert('xx');
```

However, it’s not working. Any ideas? No jQuery answers, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an element exist into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174122/how-to-check-if-an-element-exist-into-another-element)

Comment: @dcc I wanted a non-jQuery solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783280/check-if-div-with-certain-class-name-exists

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is an *array-like object*. You can check its `length` to determine if elements with defined class exist:

```
var isMobileVersion = document.getElementsByClassName('snake--mobile');
if (isMobileVersion.length > 0) {
    // elements with class "snake--mobile" exist
}
```

Comment: I got this `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'`

Answer (score 15):

Here is very sample solution for check class (hasClass) in Javascript:

```js
const mydivclass = document.querySelector('.mydivclass');
// if 'hasClass' is exist on 'mydivclass'
if(mydivclass.classList.contains('hasClass')) {
    // do something if 'hasClass' is exist.
}
```

Comment: Yup, "contains" is the way to go here...   ex. `if( document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('special-class') ) { console.log('Found!') }`

Comment: Thanks a lot `querySelector` solved the problem now I got `null` if the class isn't existing.

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. It will never be `null`. It might have a `.length` of `0`.

Comment: @Salem — Umm. Yes? So `getElementsByClassName` *doesn't* return `null` and `[0]` is `undefined` because it has a `length` of `0` … just like this answer says.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested it. its completely working . you might done any other mistake. **getElementsByClassName** return **empty** if no element found with given class name or return list of elements that have given class. so you can access it using index.

```js
var isMobileVersion = document.getElementsByClassName('snake--mobile');
if (isMobileVersion.length > 0) {
  isMobileVersion[0].style.color="red";
  alert('class exist');
}
```

```html
<div id="snake" class="snake--mobile">Class Exist div </div>
```

Comment: **You are wrong.** `getElementsByClassName` never returns `null`. In your example you check the result for being not `null`, which will always be `true`, as `NodeList` object is not falsy. Try checking against "class *not* exist" and you will see.

Comment: i have checked my example. it will return empty object if class not found. thanx @VisioN for correcting my mistake

Comment: Nevertheless, your update didn't fix the problem, as `if (x)` will still check for `true` value. The only way to assess if elements exist is to compare `length` property with `0`, as was described in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**querySelector()** method from document returns the first Element that matches the specified selector otherwise returns **null** if there is no match [query selector reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```
 Syntax
 element = document.querySelector(selectors);
```

```js
console.log(`existing-class element ${document.querySelector('.existing-class')}`)

console.log(`non-existing-class element ${document.querySelector('.non-existing-class')}`)

if(document.querySelector('.existing-class')) {
  alert('inside if block')
}
```

```html
<div class="existing-class">
```

*explicit null check with if statement is not required, since null is a falsey value when encountered in a boolean context, using the output of querySelector will work [falsey reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)*

Answer (score -1):

```
var id=$("#main .slides .gallery-cell.is-selected").attr('id');
var isselected = document.getElementById(id);
isselected.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center"});
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks